# QUnit Test for knockout js failing: "ReferenceError: ViewModel is not defined"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, knockout.js, requirejs, qunit

Below is the code for my ViewModel, test.html and test.js:

1. Viewmodel (name of the viewmodel is TestPersonName.js)

   ```
   define(["knockout"], function (ko) {   
       "use strict";
       function PersonNameViewModel () {
           var self = this;
           self.firstName = ko.observable();
           self.lastName = ko.observable();

          self.initFullName = function() { 
             return (self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName());
           }        

           initFullName();
         };
         return PersonNameViewModel ;
   });
   ```
2. Test.html file

   ```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>QUnit Example</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-1.18.0.css">
    </head>
   <body>
     <div id="qunit"></div>
     <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>  

     <script src="qunit-1.18.0.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./knockout-3.3.0.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./require.js"></script>
     <!-- Source js file -->
     <script src="TestPersonName.js"></script>
     <!-- Test js file -->
     <script src="./Test.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   I have downloaded QUnit js/css from https://qunitjs.com/

   Require.js file is used from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrburke/requirejs/dev2.1/require.js
3. Test.js file

   ```
    test("FullNameTest", function () {
        var model = new PersonNameViewModel();
        model.firstName("fn");
        model.lastName("ln");          
        equal("fn ln",model.initFullName(), "full name built properly");
    });
   ```

Executing Test.html (in Chrome) gives the following error:

> My QUnit Tests: FullNameTest (1, 0, 1)
>
> Died on test #1     at file:///D:/Test.js:23:9: PersonNameViewModel is not defined
>   Source:
>     ReferenceError: PersonNameViewModel is not defined
>     at Object. (file:///D:/Test.js:24:29)

However, when I re-write my Knockout code (`TestPersonName.js`) to the below pattern, the QUnit test passes and works perfectly fine.

```
var PersonNameViewModel = function() {
     "use strict";
  var self = this;

  self.firstName = ko.observable();
  self.lastName = ko.observable();

  self.initFullName = function() { 
     return (self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName());
  };
 };
```

The issue is that I need to follow pattern specified at top for `TestPersonName.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a *main* javascript file as your entry point for requirejs.

I would put my tests into this *main* file too. Have a look at this example:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-1.18.0.css">
 </head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>  

  <script src="qunit-1.18.0.js"></script>
  <script data-main="test" src="./require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: './jquery-2.1.3',
        knockout: './knockout-3.3.0',
        personNameViewModel: './TestPersonName'
    }
});

define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'personNameViewModel'], function($, ko, viewModel){
test("FullNameTest", function () {
     var model = new viewModel();
     model.firstName("fn");
     model.lastName("ln");          
     equal("fn ln",model.initFullName(), "full name built properly");
 });
});
```

I have removed the script references to knockout, jquery and TestPersonName from the html file. Requirejs will insert the script references for you when it runs.. And `test.js` will be the entry point for this test which will run when requirejs loads, notice the `data-main` attribute on the script tag that references requirejs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it was very helpful.
However I am running my test cases using phatomjs from Command Line and facing inconsistency in execution.
Sometimes only the test cases are identified and executed, else mostly it says "0 of 0 tests successful."
My final aim is to automate these using ant build.

I am using following phatomjs commandline runner utility:
https://github.com/leedavidr/qunit/blob/master/addons/phantomjs/runner.js

Answer (score 0):

@Anish Thanks for the reply it was very helpful.
However I am running my test cases using phatomjs from Command Line and facing inconsistency in execution.
Sometimes only the test cases are identified and executed, else mostly it says "0 of 0 tests successful."
My final aim is to automate these using ant build.

I am using following phatomjs commandline runner utility:
https://github.com/leedavidr/qunit/blob/master/addons/phantomjs/runner.js